# Parsing blk.dat file fails, is this block legitimate?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, raw-transaction, transaction-version

I'm parsing in blocks from my local blk*.dat files, using this [excellent website](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/blkdat) as a guide.

All goes well until file `blk00976.dat`, block `000000000000000000daf7a26d903543377d5cdddb962077e58fd11212479eea`

In my copy of the file, when the parser reaches byte `27871335`, it is about to iterate through a set of 64 transaction outputs.

When it reaches the 48th of these, it gets the value `c4f1c2b3b69c42c5` and then reads a VarInt of `fe80ffffff`. This is the [number of bytes to read for the next `scriptPubKey`](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/transaction-data).

The integer value of the VarInt is `2164260863` bytes (larger than the `blk.dat` file of `133768162` bytes).

Note the transaction begins with `ffffffff58`. Implying a version of `ffffffff`.

A hexdump of the block in question can be found here: https://blockchain.info/rawblock/000000000000000000daf7a26d903543377d5cdddb962077e58fd11212479eea?format=hex (Find "fe80ffffff" to see where I am looking)

**A. Is this transaction and/or the block legitimate?**

**B. If not, why is it in my blk.dat archive?**

**C. What does a transaction version of `ffffffff` imply?**

**D. Is the scriptPubKey size VarInt `fe80ffffff` correct?**

**E. What is the story behind this block?**

Comment: We can't know what is at byte position 27871335 in *your* blk00976.dat, as the contents of those files depends on the order in which peers gave you historical blocks. Can you perhaps include the full transaction hexdump in your question?

Comment: @PieterWuille thanks, the hexdump wouldn't fit in the question (too many chars). I've put on github: https://github.com/4c656554/SETransactionHex/blob/main/hex_dump . This is the transaction as constructed until meeting the `fe80ffffff` VarInt.

Comment: Can you compute the hash of the block it's in? (Not the claimed hash, but recompute it from the bytes in the blk file).

Comment: @PieterWuille do you mean the hash of the header? Would I not need to recompute the merkle root including the above problem tx? (which I can't figure out how to do due to big varint)...

Comment: Oh, right. My guess is just that you're seeing garbage bytes in the blk.dat file, which you should skip.

Comment: @PieterWuille perhaps, though seems odd that the block is listed at blockchain.info too in that case?

Comment: Oh, the block you link is the first segwit block (segregated witness), a softfork and associated protocol change that introduced a new block and transaction serialization format. The details are specified in BIP144: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0144.mediawiki. I strongly suspect that's the cause of what throws off your parser.

Comment: @PieterWuille got it; with help from your other answers on here as well, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A. Is this transaction and/or the block legitimate?**

Yes - assuming you accept the segwit soft fork and resulting option for BIP144 format transaction serialisation.

**B. If not, why is it in my blk.dat archive?**

Not applicable: see above.

**C. What does a transaction version of `ffffffff` imply?**

This is noise resulting from attempting to read a segwit tx with pre-segwit parsing schema.

**D. Is the scriptPubKey size VarInt `fe80ffffff` correct?**

No, this is also noise resulting from attempting to read a segwit tx with pre-segwit parsing schema.

**E. What is the story behind this block?**

Per Pieter Wuille's comment:

> ...the block you link is the first segwit block (segregated witness),
> a softfork and associated protocol change that introduced a new block
> and transaction serialization format. The details are specified in
> BIP144: github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0144.mediawiki. I
> strongly suspect that's the cause of what throws off your parser.

[Note, the block I linked is the second segwit block](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/what-was-the-number-of-the-block-in-which-segwit-got-activated-and-first-transa), but it must have been the first segwit block saved in my local .dat store so my parser hit it first.

[BIP144 link](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0144.mediawiki)

To adjust my parser to accept segwit transactions I had to add a conditional statement after reading the Input Count byte. If a value of zero (`0x00`) appears at its position, it is the "marker" byte which indicates that we are dealing with a segwit transaction. We then read the "flag" byte (which should be one (`0x01`)), and then the actual Input Count byte. Finally, we must also read the script witnesses:

Before reading the `locktime`, for each transaction input, read:

```
 NumberStackItems <VarInt>
 For each stack item:
    SizeOfStackItem <VarInt>
    StackItem <SizeofStackItem bytes>
```

See also:

- [Reference to Segwit raw transation format](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/110810/34190)
- [Parsing a SegWit transaction - what is the size of witness data?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/55234/34190)